# Como enviar dados de uma tabela para outra com o comando deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-select, trigger

Galera estou criando este `trigger` no *SQL Server*, mas não estou conseguindo obter o `id` para enviar os dados para outra tabela e excluir desta tabela.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MoveComprador
ON comprador
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO bk_comprador FROM comprador WHERE comprador.codigo = deleted;
END
GO
```

Comment: Olá.
Veja esta reposta pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14019020/2076784

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa definir a coluna "afetada" no DELETE que pretende obter.

Neste caso, utilize a instrução "deleted.SuaColuna".

Segue abaixo um script T-SQL para você adaptar a sua necessidade:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MoveComprador
ON comprador
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ID  int
  SELECT @ID = deleted.id FROM deleted;

  INSERT INTO TB_LOG (CD_REGISTRO, NM_ACAO) VALUES (@ID, 'EXCLUIDO');

END

GO
```

Para maiores informações veja:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189799.aspx